# Recive parse push notifications when my app is closed

Tags: android, parse-platform, xamarin, notifications, push

Please help me...)

I need to recive parse push notifications when my app is closed. When app is runed it's works fine, but when I close it, it breaks down.

My Application Class:

```
[Application(Name="ffc.droid.ParseApplication")]
    public class ParseApplication : Application
    {
        public ParseApplication (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();

        // Initialize the Parse client with your Application ID and .NET Key found on
        // your Parse dashboard

            ParseClient.Initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (object sender, ParsePushNotificationEventArgs e) => {
                // Show notification
            };

            ParsePush.SubscribeAsync (new string[] { "new_video", "new_news", "new_event" });
            ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync ();
        }
    }
```

My AndroidManiFest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.4" package="ffc.droid" android:versionCode="4">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="ffc.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_menu_ffk"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ffc.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:label="KFF.KZ" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_ffk" android:name="ffc.droid.ParseApplication">
        <service android:name="parse.ParsePushService" />
        <receiver android:name="parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="ffc.droid" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but if you see the repo of [git](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/Android), you need to initialize the parse options in another class and do reference in androidManifest file.